# I am using gradle but i m getting the error as build failure

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gradle

The error I am displaying below.

How could I solve this problem?

> :compileJavaD:\workspace\Safencesgradle\src\main\java\com\anzen\safences\rest\FileUploadService.java:17:
>   error: package org.springframework.mock.web does not exist import
>   org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
>                                      ^ D:\workspace\Safencesgradle\src\main\java\com\anzen\safences\rest\FileUploadService.java:43:
>   error: cannot find symbol             MultipartFile result = new
>   MockMultipartFile(fileFormDataContentDisposition.getName() 
>                                        ^   symbol:   class MockMultipartFile   location: class FileUploadService

Comment: looks like you are missing a dependency for the spring jar containing `org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile`

Answer (score -1):

Please import the jar spring-mock.xxx.jar (org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile) to the gradle configuration.

Put the following piece of code in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
 testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-mock', version: '2.0.8'
}
```

Comment: I have added this dependency then I tried to build in console i m getting this above mentioned error.